# Determining an expression problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Determine an expression, in simplified form, for the slope of the secant $PQ$ with $P(1,2)$ and $Q(1+h, f(1+h))$ where $f(x) = 2x^2$

I don't even know how to approach such a question. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

I know the answer is either:

a. $4 + 2h$
b. $4 - 2h$
c. $8 - 4h$
d. $8 + 4h$

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for help writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Hint: go, get the math book your teacher is using and read it. Honestly, there will be no use for you from this site, since obviously (given the nature of your all questions) you have no idea whats going on. It seems like you have no basic knowledge, or have no idea about the notions that your questions are about.

Comment: (Note: Tomas doesn't necessarily speak for anyone besides himself. If you are *that* lost, though, you should seek personal attention.)

Answer (score 2):

As $f(x)=2x^2, f(1+h)=2(1+h)^2$

So, the slope will be $$\frac{f(1+h)-2}{1+h-1}$$

Comment: Is the answer 4 + 2h?

Comment: @mathgeek101, yes provided $h\ne0$ (why?)

Comment: @amWhy, I left the last calculation for the user which  he had re-confirmed. See his comment above

Answer (score 1):

> I don't even know how to approach such a question.

That's no good! Hopefully we can get you on track...
Most of the time, the problem will tell you what it wants, often using an imperative verb.

In this case, it says **"Determine..."**, but determine *what?!?*
A slope.

So if you don't know the standard formula for slope: $$m = \dfrac{y_2 -y_1}{x_2 -x_1}$$
... you're gonna have a bad time (as the saying goes).

We can rewrite the slope formula using whatever letters we like, so maybe the following will prove useful: $$m = \dfrac{P_2 - P_1}{Q_2 - Q_1}$$

... where $(P_1, P_2) = (1,2)$ and $(Q_1, Q_2) = (1 + h, 2(1+h)^2)$

From here, you should arrive at the same conclusion as in the other answer(s).

Comment: +1 (And my earlier "not so fitting" comment posted elsewhere now deleted.) ;-)